# Haskell FFI : Using data types in a C program

Tags: c, haskell, ffi

I wrote a library with Haskell and I would like it to be used in C programs. I have read some documentation about using the `foreign export ccall` command and the `Foreign` module.

I have seen some example such as [this one](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/FFI#Calling_Haskell_from_C) but these examples use common C types like `Int` or `Double`.

In my library, I created some data types like :

```
data OrdSymb = SEQ
             | SLT
             | SGT
```

or recursives with a supplied type  :

```
data MyType a =
        TypeDouble Double
      | TypeInt Int
      | TypeVar a 
      | TypeAdd (MyType a) (MyType a)
```

But I didn't find how to use/export these types with the FFI.

**How can I export my own data types to C and use them in the `foreign` declarations to export my functions ?**

Comment: How do you expect to read these values out on the C side? Now, write out a Haskell data type that sort of matches the C one, and make a `Storable` instance for it. Voila. You can mention that type in your `foreign export`.

Comment: `Ptr a` is allowed in foreign declarations for any `a`, and in particular `Ptr (MyType a)` is therefore allowed. Of course the data will be opaque on the C side -- you will need to provide an API for observing facts about these pointers -- but that's SOP for complicated C libraries anyway.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The short answer to your question is:

- As has been suggested here and in the comments to your related question, start by fully designing your C API, including the C data representations and C functions you expect to be able to use from C code.  This is not a trivial step.  The design decisions you make here will influence the approach you take to exporting (AKA marshaling) these Haskell types out to C and back.
- Use a "C-to-Haskell" helper to automate the nuts and bolts of sizing, alignment, and structure member access.  Either `hsc2hs` or `c2hs` or both may be helpful.  These tools aren't design for *exporting* Haskell functions to C, but they are still useful.
- Expect to spend a lot of time reading up on the whole FFI subsystem, studying the generated output from the aforementioned tools, and writing lots of C glue.  Any non-trivial language binding is complex, and the fact that you're trying to expose a library written in a "high level" language through bindings in a "low level" language makes it all the more challenging.

Now, here's a (very, very) long answer to your question that will actually give you something to work with.  First some needed imports:

```
-- file: MyLib1.hs
module MyLib1 where

import Control.Exception.Base
import Foreign
import Foreign.C
```

### Binding for an Enum

Let's start with your first data type, a simple sum type with 0-ary constructors:

```
data OrdSymb = SEQ | SLT | SGT deriving (Show, Eq)
```

To be concrete, let's assume we also have some symbols:

```
newtype Symbol = Symbol String
```

and we'd like to expose Haskell functions with the following signatures:

```
compareSymb :: Symbol -> Symbol -> OrdSymb
compareSymb (Symbol x) (Symbol y) =
  case compare x y of { EQ -> SEQ; LT -> SLT; GT -> SGT }

checkSymb :: Symbol -> OrdSymb -> Symbol -> Bool
checkSymb x ord y = compareSymb x y == ord
```

Admittedly, `checkSymb` is stupid, but I wanted to show examples of functions that both produce `OrdSymb` results and accept `OrdSymb` arguments.

Here's the C interface we'd like to have for these data types and functions.  A natural C representation for a sum type with 0-ary constructors is an enum, so we get something like the following:

```
enum ord_symb {
        SLT = -1,
        SEQ = 0,
        SGT = 1
};
```

Symbols can just be represented by pointers to NUL-terminated C strings:

```
typedef char* symbol;
```

and the signatures for the exported functions will look something like:

```
enum ord_symb compare_symb(symbol x, symbol y);
bool check_symb(symbol x, enum ord_symb ord, symbol y);
```

Here's how to create the C language binding completely manually, with no C-to-Haskell helper.  It's a little tedious, but seeing it will help you understand what's going on under the hood.

We'll need an explicit mapping, for the `OrdSymb` type, between the Haskell constructor representation (`SLT`, `SEQ`, and `SGT`) and the C representation as an integer (-1, 0, or 1).  You could do this with a couple of plain functions (e.g., `toOrdSymb` and `fromOrdSymb`), though Haskell provides an `Enum` class with some functions that fit this description:

```
instance Enum OrdSymb where

  toEnum (-1) = SLT
  toEnum 0    = SEQ
  toEnum 1    = SGT

  fromEnum SLT = -1
  fromEnum SEQ = 0
  fromEnum SGT = 1
```

For documentation purposes, it's also helpful to define a type to represent the C-side type `enum ord_symb`.  The C standard says that enums have the same representation as `int`s, so we'll write:

```
type C_OrdSymb = CInt
```

Now, because `OrdSymb` is a simple type, it *might* make sense to create a `Storable` instance that can marshal its values to and from a C `enum ord_symb` in preallocated memory.  That would look like this:

```
instance Storable OrdSymb where
  sizeOf _ = sizeOf (undefined :: C_OrdSymb)
  alignment _ = alignment (undefined :: C_OrdSymb)
  peek ptr = genToEnum <$> peek (castPtr ptr :: Ptr C_OrdSymb)
  poke ptr val = poke (castPtr ptr :: Ptr C_OrdSymb) (genFromEnum val)
```

where we've used the helper functions:

```
genToEnum :: (Integral a, Enum b) => a -> b
genToEnum = toEnum . fromIntegral

genFromEnum :: (Integral a, Enum b) => b -> a
genFromEnum = fromIntegral . fromEnum
```

The `peek` and `poke` here just wrap the corresponding methods for plain `CInt`s, and they use the `toEnum` and `fromEnum` methods defined above to perform the actual transformation.

Note that this `Storable` instance isn't technically required.  We can marshal `OrdSymb`s in and out of C `enum ord_symb`s without such an instance, and in fact in the examples below, that's what we'll do.  However, the `Storable` could come in handy if we later have to work with a C structure that contains an `enum ord_symb` member, or if we find we're marshaling arrays of `enum ord_symb`s or something.

However, it's worth bearing in mind that -- generally speaking -- objects that are marshaled to and from C don't *need* to be `Storable`, and making something `Storable` doesn't magically take care of all the details of marshaling.  In particular, if we tried to write a `Storable` instance for `Symbol`, we'd run into trouble.  `Storable`s are supposed to be of predetermined length, so `sizeOf` isn't supposed to inspect it's argument.  However, a `Symbol`'s size depends on the underlying string, so unless we decide to implement a maximum string length and store all `Symbol`s that way, we shouldn't use a `Storable` instance here.  Instead, let's write some marshaling functions for `Symbol`s without the benefit of the `Storable` class:

```
peekSymbol :: Ptr Symbol -> IO Symbol
peekSymbol ptr = Symbol <$> peekCString (castPtr ptr)

newSymbol :: Symbol -> IO (Ptr Symbol)
newSymbol (Symbol str) = castPtr <$> newCString str

freeSymbol :: Ptr Symbol -> IO ()
freeSymbol = free
```

Note that we don't "poke" symbols, because we don't normally have a pre-allocated buffer of the correct size into which we're writing the symbol.  Instead, when we want to marshal a `Symbol` out to C, we'll need to allocate a new C string for it, and that's what `newSymbol` does.  To avoid a memory leak, we'll need to call `freeSymbol` (or just `free`) on symbols once we're done with them (or let the user of our C bindings know that they are responsible for calling the C function `free` on the pointer).  This also means it may be helpful to write a helper that can be used to wrap a computation that uses a marshalled symbol without leaking the memory.  Again, this is something we won't actually use in this example, but it's a helpful sort of thing to define:

```
withSymbol :: Symbol -> (Ptr Symbol -> IO a) -> IO a
withSymbol sym = bracket (newSymbol sym) freeSymbol
```

Now, we can export our Haskell functions by writing wrappers that perform the marshaling:

```
mylib_compare_symb :: Ptr Symbol -> Ptr Symbol -> IO C_OrdSymb
mylib_compare_symb px py = do
  x <- peekSymbol px
  y <- peekSymbol py
  return $ genFromEnum (compareSymb x y)

mylib_check_symb :: Ptr Symbol -> C_OrdSymb -> Ptr Symbol -> IO CInt
mylib_check_symb px ord py = do
  x <- peekSymbol px
  y <- peekSymbol py
  return $ genFromEnum (checkSymb x (genToEnum ord) y)
```

Note that the `genFromEnum` in the last line is for the `Enum` instance for Haskell's `Bool` type, to turn false/true into 0/1.

Also, it's maybe worth noting that, for these wrappers, we didn't use any `Storable` instances at all!

Finally, we can export the wrapper functions to C.

```
foreign export ccall mylib_compare_symb
  :: Ptr Symbol -> Ptr Symbol -> IO C_OrdSymb
foreign export ccall mylib_check_symb
  :: Ptr Symbol -> C_OrdSymb -> Ptr Symbol -> IO CInt
```

If you put all of the above Haskell code into `MyLib1.hs`, create
`mylib.h`, `example1.c`, and `ffitypes.cabal` with contents as follows:

```
// file: mylib.h
#ifndef MYLIB_H
#define MYLIB_H

enum ord_symb {
        SLT = -1,
        SEQ = 0,
        SGT = 1
};
typedef char* symbol;   // NUL-terminated string

// don't need these signatures -- they'll be autogenerated into
// MyLib1_stub.h
//enum ord_symb compare_symb(symbol x, symbol y);
//bool check_symb(symbol x, enum ord_symb ord, symbol y);

#endif
```

and:

```
// file: example1.c
#include <HsFFI.h>
#include "MyLib1_stub.h"
#include <stdio.h>

#include "mylib.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    hs_init(&argc, &argv);

    symbol foo = "foo";
    symbol bar = "bar";

    printf("%s\n", mylib_compare_symb(foo, bar) == SGT ? "pass" : "fail");
    printf("%s\n", mylib_check_symb(foo, SGT, bar) ? "pass" : "fail");
    printf("%s\n", mylib_check_symb(foo, SEQ, bar) ? "fail" : "pass");

    hs_exit();
    return 0;
}
```

and:

```
-- file: ffitypes.cabal
name:                 ffitypes
version:              0.1.0.0
cabal-version:        >= 1.22
build-type:           Simple

executable example1
  main-is:            example1.c
  other-modules:      MyLib1
  include-dirs:       .
  includes:           mylib.h
  build-depends:      base
  default-language:   Haskell2010
  cc-options:         -Wall -O
  ghc-options:        -Wall -Wno-incomplete-patterns -O
```

and put everything in a fresh `ffitypes` directory.  Then, from that directory:

```
$ stack init
$ stack build
$ stack exec example1
```

should work to run the example.

### Marshaling a Parameterized, Recursive Type

Now, let's turn to your more complicated `MyType`.  I've changed the `Int` to an `Int32` so it'll match a `CInt` on typical platforms.

```
data MyType a =
        TypeDouble Double
      | TypeInt Int32
      | TypeVar a 
      | TypeAdd (MyType a) (MyType a)
```

This is a sum type with unary and binary constructors, an arbitrary type parameter `a`, and recursive structure, so pretty complicated. Again, it's important to begin by specifying a concrete C implementation.  A C union can be used to store a complicated sum type, but we'll also want to "tag" the union with a enum to indicate which constructor the union is representing, so the C type will look something like this:

```
typedef struct mytype_s {
        enum mytype_cons_e {
                TYPEDOUBLE,
                TYPEINT,
                TYPEVAR,
                TYPEADD
        } mytype_cons;
        union {
                double type_double;
                int type_int;
                void* type_var;
                struct {
                        struct mytype_s *left;
                        struct mytype_s *right;
                } type_add;
        } mytype_value;
} mytype;
```

Note that, to allow the C bindings to work with `MyType a`s with multiple possible parameters `a`, we need to use a `void*` for the `type_var` union member.

Writing the marshalling functions for `MyType` entirely manually is very painful and error prone.  There are a lot of details about the exact size, alignment, and layout of C structures that you'd need to get right.  Instead, we'll use the `c2hs` helper package.  We'll start with a little preamble at the top of a new `MyLib2.chs`:

```
-- file: MyLib2.chs
module MyLib2 where

import Foreign
import Foreign.C

#include "mylib.h"
```

The `c2hs` package is great for working with enums.  For example, creating marshalling infrastructure for the `enum mytype_cons_e` tag with this package looks like this:

```
-- file: MyLib2.chs
{#enum mytype_cons_e as MyTypeCons {}#}
```

Note that this *automatically* retrieves the definition from the C header `mylib.h`, creates a Haskell definition equivalent to:

```
-- data MyTypeCons = TYPEDOUBLE | TYPEINT | etc.
```

and defines the needed `Enum` instance to map the Haskell constructors to and from the integer values on the C side.  It'll be useful to have our generalized `toEnum` and `fromEnum` helpers here, too:

```
genToEnum :: (Integral a, Enum b) => a -> b
genToEnum = toEnum . fromIntegral

genFromEnum :: (Integral a, Enum b) => b -> a
genFromEnum = fromIntegral . fromEnum
```

Now, let's look at marshalling your data type:

```
data MyType a =
  TypeDouble Double
  | TypeInt Int32
  | TypeVar a 
  | TypeAdd (MyType a) (MyType a)
```

to and from a `struct mytype_s`.  One warning: these implementations assume that the recursive constructor `TypeAdd` and its C analogue `type_add` are never used to create "cycles" on the C or Haskell side.  Handling data structures that are recursive in the sense that `let x = 0:x` is recursive would require a different approach.

Because `struct mytype_s` is a fixed-length structure, you might think it would be a good candidate for a `Storable` instance, but that turns out not to be the case.  Because of the embedded pointer in the `type_var` union member and the recursive pointers in the `type_add` member, it's not possible to write a reasonable `Storable` instance for `MyType`.  We *could* write one for:

```
data C_MyType a =
  C_TypeDouble Double
  | C_TypeInt Int32
  | C_TypeVar (Ptr a)
  | C_TypeAdd (Ptr (MyType a)) (Ptr (MyType a))
```

where the pointers have been made explicit.  When we marshall this, we'll assume we've already marshalled the "child" nodes and have pointers to them that we can marshall out to the structure.  For the `C_TypeAdd` constructor, I could have written this instead:

```
  -- C_TypeAdd (Ptr (C_MyType a)) (Ptr (C_MyType a))
```

It doesn't really matter, since we'll be freely casting `Ptr`s back and forth between `MyType`s and `C_MyType`s .  I decided to use my definition because it got rid of two `castPtr` calls.

The `Storable` instance for `C_MyType` looks like this.  Note how `c2hs` allows us to look up sizes, alignments, and offsets automatically.  We'd have to calculate these all manually otherwise.

```
instance Storable (C_MyType a) where
  sizeOf _ = {#sizeof mytype_s#}
  alignment _ = {#alignof mytype_s#}
  peek p = do
    typ <- genToEnum <$> {#get struct mytype_s->mytype_cons#} p
    case typ of
      TYPEDOUBLE ->
        C_TypeDouble . (\(CDouble x) -> x)
        <$> {#get struct mytype_s->mytype_value.type_double#} p
      TYPEINT    ->
        C_TypeInt    . (\(CInt    x) -> x)
        <$> {#get struct mytype_s->mytype_value.type_int   #} p
      TYPEVAR    ->
        C_TypeVar . castPtr <$> {#get struct mytype_s->mytype_value.type_var#} p
      TYPEADD    -> do
        q1 <- {#get struct mytype_s->mytype_value.type_add.left#} p
        q2 <- {#get struct mytype_s->mytype_value.type_add.right#} p
        return $ C_TypeAdd (castPtr q1) (castPtr q2)
  poke p t = case t of
    C_TypeDouble x -> do
      tag TYPEDOUBLE
      {#set struct mytype_s->mytype_value.type_double#} p (CDouble x)
    C_TypeInt x    -> do
      tag TYPEINT
      {#set struct mytype_s->mytype_value.type_int   #} p (CInt    x)
    C_TypeVar q    -> do
      tag TYPEVAR
      {#set struct mytype_s->mytype_value.type_var   #} p (castPtr q)
    C_TypeAdd q1 q2 -> do
      tag TYPEADD
      {#set struct mytype_s->mytype_value.type_add.left #} p (castPtr q1)
      {#set struct mytype_s->mytype_value.type_add.right#} p (castPtr q2)

    where
      tag = {#set struct mytype_s->mytype_cons#} p . genFromEnum
```

With the `Storable` instance for `C_MyType` out of the way, the marshalling functions for a *real* `MyType` look pretty clean:

```
peekMyType :: (Ptr a -> IO a) -> Ptr (MyType a) -> IO (MyType a)
peekMyType peekA p = do
  ct <- peek (castPtr p)
  case ct of
    C_TypeDouble x -> return $ TypeDouble x
    C_TypeInt    x -> return $ TypeInt    x
    C_TypeVar    q -> TypeVar <$> peekA q
    C_TypeAdd q1 q2 -> do
      t1 <- peekMyType peekA q1
      t2 <- peekMyType peekA q2
      return $ TypeAdd t1 t2

newMyType :: (a -> IO (Ptr a)) -> MyType a -> IO (Ptr (MyType a))
newMyType newA t = do
  p <- malloc
  case t of
    TypeDouble x  -> poke p (C_TypeDouble x)
    TypeInt    x  -> poke p (C_TypeInt    x)
    TypeVar    v  -> poke p . C_TypeVar =<< newA v
    TypeAdd t1 t2 -> do
      q1 <- newMyType newA t1
      q2 <- newMyType newA t2
      poke p (C_TypeAdd q1 q2)
  return (castPtr p)  -- case from Ptr C_MyType to Ptr MyType

freeMyType :: (Ptr a -> IO ()) -> Ptr (MyType a) -> IO ()
freeMyType freeA p = do
  ct <- peek (castPtr p)
  case ct of
    C_TypeVar q -> freeA q
    C_TypeAdd q1 q2 -> do
      freeMyType freeA q1
      freeMyType freeA q2
    _ -> return ()  -- no children to free
  free p
```

Note how we need to use helpers for the `a` type.  Whenever we want to make a `newMyType` for a `MyType a`, we'll need to provide a tailored `newA` for the `a` type.  It would be possible to make this into a typeclass and even create an instance for all `Storable a`, but I haven't done that here.

Now, suppose we have a Haskell function that uses all these data types that we'd like to export to C:

```
replaceSymbols :: OrdSymb -> Symbol -> Symbol -> MyType Symbol -> MyType Symbol
replaceSymbols ord sym1 sym2 = go
  where
    go (TypeVar s) | checkSymb s ord sym1 = TypeVar sym2
    go (TypeAdd t1 t2) = TypeAdd (go t1) (go t2)
    go rest = rest
```

with the helper functions previously defined:

```
compareSymb :: Symbol -> Symbol -> OrdSymb
compareSymb (Symbol x) (Symbol y) =
  case compare x y of { EQ -> SEQ; LT -> SLT; GT -> SGT }

checkSymb :: Symbol -> OrdSymb -> Symbol -> Bool
checkSymb x ord y = compareSymb x y == ord
```

We'll need a few other things in `MyLib2.chs`.  First, we'll use `c2hs` to define the `OrdSymb` type (again, this automatically generates the associated `data OrdSymb`):

```
{#enum ord_symb as OrdSymb {} deriving (Show, Eq)#}
type C_OrdSymb = CInt
```

and the symbol-marshalling code copied from `MyLib1.hs`:

```
newtype Symbol = Symbol String

peekSymbol :: Ptr Symbol -> IO Symbol
peekSymbol ptr = Symbol <$> peekCString (castPtr ptr)

newSymbol :: Symbol -> IO (Ptr Symbol)
newSymbol (Symbol str) = castPtr <$> newCString str

freeSymbol :: Ptr Symbol -> IO ()
freeSymbol = free
```

Then, we can write the following C wrapper:

```
mylib_replace_symbols :: C_OrdSymb -> Ptr Symbol -> Ptr Symbol
    -> Ptr (MyType Symbol) -> IO (Ptr (MyType Symbol))
mylib_replace_symbols ord psym1 psym2 pt = do
  sym1 <- peekSymbol psym1
  sym2 <- peekSymbol psym2
  t <- peekMyType peekSymbol pt
  let t' = replaceSymbols (genToEnum ord) sym1 sym2 t
  newMyType newSymbol t'
```

Given that this returns a malloced data structure, it's helpful to also provide an exported function to free it:

```
mylib_free_mytype_symbol :: Ptr (MyType Symbol) -> IO ()
mylib_free_mytype_symbol = freeMyType freeSymbol
```

And let's export them:

```
foreign export ccall mylib_replace_symbols
  :: C_OrdSymb -> Ptr Symbol -> Ptr Symbol
       -> Ptr (MyType Symbol) -> IO (Ptr (MyType Symbol))
foreign export ccall mylib_free_mytype_symbol
  :: Ptr (MyType Symbol) -> IO ()
```

If you take all the Haskell code in this section, starting with the `module MyLib2` line and put it in `MyLib2.chs`, then create/modify the following files:

```
// file: mylib.h
#ifndef MYLIB_H
#define MYLIB_H

enum ord_symb {
    SLT = -1,
    SEQ = 0,
    SGT = 1
};
typedef char* symbol;   // NUL-terminated string

typedef struct mytype_s {
    enum mytype_cons_e {
        TYPEDOUBLE,
        TYPEINT,
        TYPEVAR,
        TYPEADD
    } mytype_cons;
    union {
        double type_double;
        int type_int;
        void* type_var;
        struct {
            struct mytype_s *left;
            struct mytype_s *right;
        } type_add;
    } mytype_value;
} mytype;

#endif
```

and:

```
// file: example2.c
#include <HsFFI.h>
#include "MyLib2_stub.h"
#include <stdio.h>

#include "mylib.h"

// AST for:   1.0 + foo
mytype node1 = { TYPEDOUBLE, {type_double: 1.0} };
mytype node2 = { TYPEVAR,    {type_var: "foo"} };
mytype root  = { TYPEADD,    {type_add: {&node1, &node2} } };

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    hs_init(&argc, &argv);

    mytype *p1 = mylib_replace_symbols(SEQ, "foo", "bar", &root);
    printf("%s\n",  // should print "bar"
       (char*) p1->mytype_value.type_add.right->mytype_value.type_var);
    mytype *p2 = mylib_replace_symbols(SEQ, "quux", "bar", &root);
    printf("%s\n",  // unchanged -- should still be "foo"
       (char*) p2->mytype_value.type_add.right->mytype_value.type_var);

    mylib_free_mytype_symbol(p1);
    mylib_free_mytype_symbol(p2);

    hs_exit();
    return 0;
}
```

and add the `executable example2` clause to your Cabal file:

```
-- file: ffitypes.cabal
name:                 ffitypes
version:              0.1.0.0
cabal-version:        >= 1.22
build-type:           Simple

executable example1
  main-is:            example1.c
  other-modules:      MyLib1
  include-dirs:       .
  includes:           mylib.h
  build-depends:      base
  default-language:   Haskell2010
  cc-options:         -Wall -O
  ghc-options:        -Wall -Wno-incomplete-patterns -O

executable example2
  main-is:            example2.c
  other-modules:      MyLib2
  include-dirs:       .
  includes:           mylib.h
  build-depends:      base
  build-tools:        c2hs
  default-language:   Haskell2010
  cc-options:         -Wall -O
  ghc-options:        -Wall -Wno-incomplete-patterns -O
```

and stick them all in the `ffitypes` directory, then you should be able to `stack build` and `stack exec example2`.

### Language Bindings are Hard!

As you can perhaps tell from the code above, it takes a lot of work to create even simple C bindings for Haskell libraries.  If it's any consolation, creating Haskell bindings for C libraries is only a little bit easier.  Best of luck!

Comment: will apache's `thrift` help in this case ? only need to annotate the data type and function signature ?